# IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED aiplatform.googleapis.com

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, vertex

I am currently building a node.js script to send a predict request to a Vertex AI endpoint and receive response data back from that. I created a service account with the aiplatform/developer role. I made sure that these permissions were project-level. The script works when I authenticate using the gcloud CLI on my local computer. However, this script will be hosted on a cloud server and I need to use the service account JSON key to authenticate. This is my script below:

```
const aiplatform = require('@google-cloud/aiplatform');
const { PredictionServiceClient } = aiplatform.v1;
const { helpers } = aiplatform;
require('dotenv').config();

const project_id = '*******';
const location = 'us-central1';
const endpoint_id = '***************';

const client = new PredictionServiceClient({apiEndpoint: "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com"});

async function predictor(instanceData) {
    for (const instance of instanceData) {
        await predict([instance]);
    }
}

async function predict(instances) {
    const endpoint = `projects/${project_id}/locations/${location}/endpoints/${endpoint_id}`;
    try {
        const request = {
          endpoint: endpoint,
          instances: instances,
        };
        const [response] = await client.predict(request);
        parseAndPrintResponse(response);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error during prediction:', e);
    }
}

function parseAndPrintResponse(response) {
    response.predictions.forEach((prediction, idx) => {
        console.log(`Results for Instance ${idx + 1}:`);
        const classes = prediction.structValue.fields.classes.listValue.values.map(v => v.stringValue);
        const scores = prediction.structValue.fields.scores.listValue.values.map(v => v.numberValue);

        classes.forEach((classValue, index) => {
            const score = scores[index];
            console.log(`  Value ${classValue}: ${(score * 100).toFixed(2)}% for ${classValue}`);
        });
    });
}

const instances = [
    {
        "req": "get",
        "type": "query",
        "param": "pages-Size",
        "desc": "Optional filter by items that are missing episodes or not.",
        "dtype": "boolean",
        "bool": "false",
        "b1": "",
        "b2": "",
        "b3": "",
        "b4": "",
        "b5": "",
        "b6": "",
        "zero": "0"
    }
];

const formattedInstances = instances.map(instance => helpers.toValue(instance));

predictor(formattedInstances);
```

The .env file has the route to the JSON key.But when running this script, I still get the IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED error.

Comment: 1) My guess is that your code is fetching credentials from the Google service's Metadata server. Compute services such as Functions, Run, Compute Engine, etc have an attached service account. That is preferred over specifying a service account JSON key file. 2) I do not see anywhere in your example code where you are setting up credentials to use. 3) Edit your post to specify which cloud service you are using and how you are setting up authorization (service account). Details matter to get a good/correct answer.